# Is there a way to add links to flexbox images?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This works (images with no links):

```
<div id="gallery">
     <img src="1.jpg"/>
     <img src="2.jpg"/>
     <img src="3.jpg"/>
     <img src="4.jpg"/>
</div>
```

```
 #gallery {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 4px;
  }
  
  #gallery img {
    width: 25%;
    height: 300px;
    object-fit: cover;
    margin-top: 8px;
    padding: 0 4px;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
```

This totally messes up the .css (images with links):

```
<div id="gallery">
     <a href="1.jpg"><img src="1.jpg"/></a>
     <a href="2.jpg"><img src="2.jpg"/></a>
     <a href="3.jpg"><img src="3.jpg"/></a>
     <a href="4.jpg"><img src="4.jpg"/></a>
</div>
```

The only thing that makes it somewhat better is adding:

```
#gallery a {
    width: 100%;
}
```

But then it's just a vertical stack of images.
So does flexbox just not allow images as links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-apply the styles from `img` to `a` because flexbox applies to direct children only

```css
#gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

#gallery a {
  width: 25%;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  padding: 0 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#gallery img {
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery">
  <a href="1.jpg"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=1" /></a>
  <a href="2.jpg"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=2" /></a>
  <a href="3.jpg"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=3" /></a>
  <a href="4.jpg"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=4" /></a>
</div>
```